# Control web apps via Google Assistant

Tags: android, actions-on-google, app-actions

I am evaluating whether to build a native Android app vs. a progressive web app (PWA). PWAs seem to gain a lot of traction recently, and especially on Android with Chrome (+ Desktop) seem to support a lot of functionalities and access to device APIs.

What I can't find anything about:

Is it possible to integrate a PWA with Google Assistant the same way as a native app? Assume I want to build an Audio app, can I make it work with Google Assistant even in the form of a PWA? Not talking about just having the assistant open the app - it should be able to also handle request such as "play 50 cent on app_name" etc.

Besides the voice assistant integration, any other thoughts on why I should or should not build a PWA vs. a native Android app?

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Actions that can interact with web apps via voic ewill only be approved for games at the current time.